# create multiple arrays from csv file using PHP

Tags: php, csv, curl, append

I have csv file with 1500+ entries in a column.I can able to read csv file's all values of column with this.

```
        $rowcount = 1;
        $srcFileName = "input/test.csv";
        $file = fopen($srcFileName,"r");
        $inputfielscount = count(file($srcFileName, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
        while($rowcount < $inputfielscount) 
        {
          $row = fgetcsv($file);
          $result=array("id" =>$row[0],"des"=>"I am jhon",salery="10000");
          $Final=array("listingsEmp"=>$result);
        }
```

After reading first (1-10) value i will create an array (like array [0] =>$result) and Then wantto repeat same task from (11-20) and create another array (like array [1] =>$Final  this time $final array contain information about the next ids whic we read from csv file (11-10)) and so on.

For the above requirment i changed code to this :

```
        $rowcount = 1;
        $srcFileName = "input/test.csv";
        $file = fopen($srcFileName,"r");
        while($rowcount < 20) 
        {

             if(($rowcount % 10 == 0) && ( $rowcount != 0)) {
                 $rowcount++;
                break;
             }else{

                  $row = fgetcsv($file);
                 // some curl code for fetching data according to csv file field(Id)
                  $result=array("id" =>$row[0],"des"=>"I am jhon",salery="10000"); //contain 10 array 

             }
        }

    $Final=array("listingsEmp"=>$result);
```

Now i will post this $final array which has (0-10 index array ,each has unique id and corresponding values) using curl and get response which i am save in csv file.

```
        $currenttime=date("Y-m-d-H_i_s");   
        $opfile='output'.$currenttime.'.csv'; //path wher op csv file exist 
        if(!@copy($srcFileName,'/output/'.$opfile))
        {
            $errors= error_get_last();
            echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'];
            echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
        }else { //  echo "File copied from remote!";
            $fp = fopen('output/output'.$currenttime.'.csv',"a");
            $fr = fopen($srcFileName,"r");
            $rowcounts=0;
            $FinalRES=$Final->response;

            while($rowcounts< $inputfielscount) {
                    $resultBulk=$FinalRES[$rowcounts];
                    $resultBulkStatus=$FinalRES->status;
                    $resultBulkErrors=$FinalRES->errors;
                    $errorMsgArray=$resultBulkErrors[0];
                    $BulkErrorsMessage=$errorMsgArray->message;
                    $rows = fgetcsv($fr);
                        if($resultBulkStatus=='failure'){
                                    $list = array ($rows[0],$rows[1],$resultBulkStatus,$BulkErrorsMessage);
                        }else {
                                    $list = array ($rows[0],$rows[1],$resultBulkStatus,"successfully");
                        }
                    fputcsv($fp,$list);
                        //$p++;
                        $rowcounts++;
            }
        }
```

This full code runs once and give response for 10 ids ,i want repeat this code again for next 10 id (11-20)and then for (21-30) so on   .
Once all response write in output csv file  After that it display download output file link,Output file contain full response for all Ids  which is in csv file(1500 +)

```
    <?php   $dnldfilw='output'.$currenttime.'.csv';?>
            <a href='download.php?filename=<?php echo $dnldfilw; ?>'>Download Output file</a>

        ?>
```

Comment: Why are using two or three methods for reading the same csv concurrently? I see `file()`, `fopen()` and `fgetcsv()`...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to just use the `file()` function you are already using...
So to shorten the code to some pseudocode:

```
<?php

    $indexedArray = array();
    $indexedSplit = 10;

    $lines = file($srcFileName);
    $tempArray = array();
    foreach($lines as $line) {
        if(count($tempArray) % $indexedSplit === 0) {
            $indexedArray[] = $tempArray;
            $tempArray = array();
        }
        $tempArray[] = $line;
    }

    foreach($indexedArray as $index => $valueArray) {
        // do the curl magic
        // write results of curl into csv
    }
```

Your question is poorly phrased, but I think this would be your aim, right?

Comment: Hi @RichardBernarde ,My requirment is ,Suppose in my csv file ther is 40 rows..I want to crate an array for each 10 rows .Like 1-10 rows will have in array1,11-20 rows will have in array2,21-30 rows will have in array3....i will have send first array1 to server get response and save into csv file.,,then send aaray2 to server and save into same csv file  justafter  array1 response,,Hope now you understand.